# AWS EC2 ECS - How many tasks should I place on a single instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

At the moment, I have a single c4.large (3.75GB RAM, 2 vCPU) instance in my workers cluster, currently running 21 tasks for 16 services. These tasks range from image processing, to data transformation, most sending HTTP requests too. As you can see, the instance is quite well utilisated.

[image: CPU and memory utilisation are also quite high]

My question is, how do I know how many tasks to place on an instance? I am placing up to 8 tasks for a service, but I'm unsure as to whether this results in a speed increase, given they are using the same underlying instance. How do I find the optimal placement?

Should I put many chefs in my kitchen, or will just two get the food out to customers faster?

Comment: As I've always understood it: aim for 80% CPU load, but make sure your IO isn't the limiting factor. I don't have any official research for this though

Comment: Yes, the norm must lower 80% (other for buffer). CPU and Memory is not enough. You must profile based on as least CPU, Memory, Network I/O, Disk I/O. Tresstest on your env and adjust/calcualte the suitable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We typically run lots of smaller sized server in our clusters. Like 4-6 t2.small for our workers and place 6-7 tasks on each. The main reason for this is not to speed up processing but reduce the blast radius of servers going down.

We've seen it quite often for a server to simply fail an instance health check and AWS take it down. Having the workers spread out reduces the effect on the system.

Comment: I was considering this, but it's a workers cluster, not a web cluster, so I feel t2 types are unsuitable?

Comment: The point is to reduce the blast radius of a single server going down. Pick the instance type that fits your needs. But pick one that you can run less tasks on and spread the tasks over more servers.

Comment: Another question John, if you don't mind. If I put 6-7 tasks on a t2.small, do I set the CPU and Memory limits accordingly? Which means giving each ~170 CPU units and 340MB of RAM. I'm trying to figure out how to balance the tasks across our instances. My boss insists that our current average of 15.8 tasks per t2.small is acceptable, but we're seeing random lock downs and slowings of tasks.

Comment: If you're seeing random lock downs & slowness due to using all your underlying instance resources - like CPU credits & Disk credits - then YES for sure you have too many tasks on that server. Unfortunately there's no magic number here. Using the binpacking placement strategy you could set the CPU & memory limits accordingly to control how many tasks get put on each server. That would work pretty well since you could autoscale your instances based on memory reservation as well. Hit me up at jveldboom[at]gmail.com - would love to share use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other people’s 80% rule. But you never want a single host for any kind of critical applications. If that goes down you’re screwed. I also think it’s better to use larger sized servers because of their increase network performance. You should look into a host with enhanced networking, especially because you say you have a lot of HTTP work.

Another thing to consider is disk I/O. If you are piling too many tasks on a host and there is a failure, it’s going to try to schedule those all somewhere else. I have had servers crash because of too many tasks being scheduled and burning through disk credits.

Comment: Correct about the single host, but luckily this is my staging workers environment in the example.